# codeigniter - foreach query not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I'm starting with codeigniter and I have a trouble with a DB query.
If I run the query in a standard PHP code, it show all data passed in the query but if I run the query using codeigniter, it show only one row with a foreach.

**In the Model:**

```
$query = $this->db->query('select C.display_name AS "Servicio", B.output AS "Status",      B.last_time_ok AS "Ultimo OK" , B.last_time_critical AS "Ultimo Critical" 
from system_hosts     AS A 
INNER JOIN system_services AS C ON C.host_object_id = A.host_object_id 
INNER JOIN     system_servicestatus AS B ON B.service_object_id = C.service_object_id 
WHERE A.alias =     "'.$hostname.'" GROUP BY C.display_name;');                 

return $query->row_array();
```

**In the view:**

```
<?php foreach ($hosts_service as $services): 
    ?>  <tr>
    <h2><td><?php echo $hosts_service['Servicio'] ?></a></td></h2>  
<h2><td><?php echo $hosts_service['Status'] ?></a></td></h2>    
<h2><td><?php echo $hosts_service['Ultimo OK'] ?></a></td></h2>     
<h2><td><?php echo $hosts_service['Ultimo Critical'] ?></a></td></h2>   </tr>    
<?php endforeach ?>
```

**In Controller:**

```
$data['hosts_service'] = $this->news_model->get_service($hostname);
```

It return the same value 4 times, but if I run in normal PHP it return the 3 different values containing in the DB, so the query is correct. ( I tried the same query in Toad and the result are OK).

¿What can be the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By returning a row_array(), you are only going to return a single row. For example:

```
get_user(user_id)
```

That would return a single result - the user I am looking for.

Try using:

```
return $query->result();
```

Check out [Generating Query Results](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `result_array()` instead of `row_array()`

try

```
return $query->result_array();
```

instead of

```
return $query->row_array();
```

See more info [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot Nouphal, your tip solves the issue partialy!! Samutz adds the rest of the solution!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nouphal.M's answer, you also need to use the item variable in the loop instead of the array variable.

```
<?php foreach ($hosts_service as $services): ?>
<tr>
    <h2><td><?php echo $services['Servicio'] ?></a></td></h2>  
    <h2><td><?php echo $services['Status'] ?></a></td></h2>    
    <h2><td><?php echo $services['Ultimo OK'] ?></a></td></h2>     
    <h2><td><?php echo $services['Ultimo Critical'] ?></a></td></h2>
</tr>    
<?php endforeach ?>
```

There's also some unrelated issues with your html. `<h2>` tags should be inside the `<td>` tags. You have a closing `<a>` tag, but no opening `<a>` tag.